# How to get data in sequelize using Noje js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

This is code i have used, fetched the all data in database, but i have not getting in value. I'm new for sequelize.

```
   Project.findAll({ raw: true}).then(function (users) {
        console.log(users);
  console.log(users.dataValues);

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Oops! something went wrong, : ', err);
    });
```

This is Output:
This is  `console.log(users);`

```
   [ DAO {
        dataValues: 
         { idProject: 1,
           projectName: 'Symfony',
           isActive: '1',
           createdAt: 2018-10-23T06:32:43.000Z,
           modifiedAt: 2018-10-23T06:32:43.000Z },
        _previousDataValues: 
         { idProject: 1,
           projectName: 'Symfony',
           isActive: '1',
           createdAt: 2018-10-23T06:32:43.000Z,
           modifiedAt: 2018-10-23T06:32:43.000Z },

        options: { isNewRecord: false, isDirty: false, raw: true },
        hasPrimaryKeys: true,
        selectedValues: 
         RowDataPacket {
           idProject: 1,
           projectName: 'Symfony',
           isActive: '1',
           createdAt: 2018-10-23T06:32:43.000Z,
           modifiedAt: 2018-10-23T06:32:43.000Z },
        __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
        isNewRecord: false }.....
```

This is  console.log(users.dataValues);

```
undefined
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **findAll**, it returns an array, as you can see here in the documentation:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll

so you should iterate over this array, like so:

```
 Project.findAll({ raw: true})
 .then(projects => {
    projects.forEach(project => {
       console.log(project);
       console.log('project name', project.projectName);
    })
 }).catch(function (err) {
     console.log('Oops! something went wrong: ', err);
 });
```

Optionally you could use Async/Await for a cleaner code:

```
 try {
   const projects = await Project.findAll({ raw: true});
   projects.forEach(project => {
        console.log('project name ', project.projectName);
   })
 } catch(err) {
     console.log('Oops! something went wrong: ', err);
 }
```